# How to replace one value calculated by COUNT with another value in SELECT result?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Suppose there are two tables

```
shop        seller
------      -------
id          id
seller_id   seller_name
goods       sallary
```

seller_id may be repeated, parts from seller.id may not be there at all. So, I need to get the result of the request consisting of saller_name and counting the number of stores on each seller. I did it like this

```
SELECT seller_name, COUNT(seller_id) AS shops FROM seller 
LEFT JOIN shop ON seller.id = shop.seller_id GROUP BY seller_name.
```

And it works. But the problem is that I need to replace all 0 in shops with the text 'none'.
I tried to do it through

```
REPLACE(COUNT(seller_id),0,"none")
```

and with

```
CASE
WHEN COUNT(seller_id)=0 THEN "none"
ELSE COUNT(seller_id)
END
```

But instead of the expected numbers and none, I get a random set of numbers and letters. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `'none'` is a string, but the value is a count.  I would strongly advise you to stick with numbers, but that is not your query.

You need to do type conversion:

```
SELECT se.seller_name,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(s.seller_id) = 0
             THEN 'none'
             ELSE CAST(COUNT(s.seller_id) AS VARCHAR(255))
        END) AS shops
FROM seller se LEFT JOIN
     shop s
     ON se.id = sh.seller_id
GROUP BY se.seller_name;
```

In MySQL, use `CAST(COUNT(s.seller_id) AS CHAR)`.  Or almost any database supports `CONCAT(COUNT(s.seller_id), '')`, but using `CONCAT()` to convert types seems misleading to me.

Comment: there is an error on ELSE CAST(COUNT(s.seller_id) AS VARCHAR(255)).

Comment: @Kaama . . . That is valid SQL syntax, although some databases may have some variation on it.  You still have not added a tag to the question for the database you are using.

Comment: my bad. i'm using SQL Fiddle for testing this code, which, in his turn, uses MySQL and SQLite, if i'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Point 1: REPLACE(COUNT(seller_id),0,"none") --It will replace all zero's with 'none'.
```

Like your count is 10 it will return **1none**  in output.

```
Point 2: CASE  WHEN COUNT(seller_id)=0 THEN "none" ELSE COUNT(seller_id) END--It will gives you conversion failed error.
```

So you need you cast the count in varchar as given below.

```
   SELECT se.seller_name,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(s.seller_id) = 0
            THEN 'none'
            ELSE CAST(COUNT(s.seller_id) AS VARCHAR(10))
        END) AS shops
FROM seller se LEFT JOIN
     shop s
     ON se.id = sh.seller_id
GROUP BY se.seller_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change yor query to something like this:

```
SELECT seller_name, 
CASE
WHEN COUNT(shop.Id)=0 THEN 'none'
ELSE CAST(COUNT(shop.Id) as NVARCHAR(10))
END AS shops FROM seller 
LEFT JOIN shop ON seller.id = shop.seller_id GROUP BY seller_name
```